# puts writing to file in expect script

Tags: tcl, expect

my `puts` command in tcl function is not working. Bascily this function is  giving feedback about validation(good, or not), but the problem is with puts. Idea is that puts write to file "Validation ok" or "Validation found error", but file /tmp/ARNE/bla has only "Validation ok". I have lots of validation, so some of them have error an some not, but the "Validation found error" is not in the file.
If anybody knows what could be the problem, I would appriciate.

```
proc functionm {} {
        set path /tmp/ARNE/bla
        set var [open $path w]
        expect {
                "There were 0 errors reported during validation" {
                 puts $var "Validation succeeded\r"

               }
        expect -re {There were [0-9] errors reported during validation} {
                  puts "Found $expect_out(0,string) errors in validation"
                  puts $var "Validation found error\r"
                  send "exit\r"
                  expect -re {janko.*}
                  #after 100
                  close
                  exit
        }
}
```

Comment: Could you please describe how `functionm` is interacting with your `spawn`ed process?

Comment: If you call this command several times, the file will be overwritten every time. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a missing `}` in your code. In your first `expect` statement, the curly-braced grouping covers both sections but I suspect you meant to have two separate expect statements with separate bodies. The following adds the missing bracing:

```
proc functionm {} {
    set path /tmp/ARNE/bla
    set var [open $path w]
    expect "There were 0 errors reported during validation" {
        puts $var "Validation succeeded\r"
    }
    expect -re {There were [0-9] errors reported during validation} {
        puts "Found $expect_out(0,string) errors in validation"
        puts $var "Validation found error\r"
        send "exit\r"
        expect -re {janko.*}
        #after 100
        close
        exit
    }
}
```

Although you might have wanted one expect statement with separate selectors. The `expect` statement operates like a `switch` statement so something like:

```
proc functionm {} {
    set path /tmp/ARNE/bla
    set var [open $path w]
    expect {
       "There were 0 errors reported during validation" {
          puts $var "Validation succeeded\r"
       }
       -re {There were [0-9] errors reported during validation} {
           puts "Found $expect_out(0,string) errors in validation"
           puts $var "Validation found error\r"
           send "exit\r"
           expect -re {janko.*}
           #after 100
           close
           exit
       }
    }
}
```

may also work ok.

Comment: Still not working, I think the problem is in puts, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Each time you call `[open $path w]` you open and erase the file. I'm not certain that you mean that as I can't see how often you call this function. If you need to append data to the file you might want to look into other open modes (eg: a+). How do you know you actually matched your expect strings?